# rpush Rails Gem :: Running via Daemon vs Scheduled Job vs Embedding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apple-push-notifications, delayed-job

Curious if anyone has any experience with the [rpush Rails Gem](https://github.com/rpush/rpush) and could shed some light on:

---

**When is the right time to use it [as a Daemon](https://github.com/rpush/rpush#as-a-daemon), [in a Scheduled Job](https://github.com/rpush/rpush#in-a-scheduled-job), or [embedding it inside an existing process](https://github.com/rpush/rpush#embedded-inside-an-existing-process)?**

---

Why I'm asking :)

I am using it in a Rails App to process APNS (and GCM eventually) messages that I've stored in a delayed-job queue (thousands of jobs run and send the messages via rpush).

Comment: how did you use it?